# Is there a super prototype "Object" of all objects in javascript? What is that Object(first letter in capital) in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Is there a super prototype "Object" of all objects in javascript? What is that Object(first letter in capital) in javascript. In javascript Object is the prototype of all objects like Object class is super class of all classes in Java.

Comment: This was supposed to be a question, immediately followed by an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean, if you place something in `Object.prototype` will it be accessible by **everything** because they all extend `Object`. The simple answer, yes.

If you place something in `Object.prototype` then when you create an instance of say, `XMLHttpRequest`, then you will be able to access what you set. Like this:

```
Object.prototype.foo = 'bar';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(req.foo); // bar
```

Comment: No, not by everything. `Object.prototype` is an object whose [[Prototype]] is null. Equally, with ES5, `Object.create(null)` creates a similar object (i.e., one whose [[Prototype]] is null).

Answer (score 0):

Just type `Object.prototype` in your console.  You will see something like

[image]

To test the hypothesis that all functions in javascript extend from `Object`, just like all classes extend from Object in Java, see the following:

[image]

So the answer is yes.

But keep in mind that javascript uses prototypal inheritance, while in javascript all objects get the methods of `Object` on their prototype, just like in Java, other similarities will not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Object` is the topmost object in prototype hierarchy. However, it's not recommended to pollute `Object.prototype` because such properties would show in, for example, `for-in` loop (if you don't make them not enumerable). Also note that in IE up to version 8, host objects don't inherit from Object: `document.body instanceof Object === false`.